# MaxWidth for DataGridVew Column

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a Winform DataGridView which uses AutoSizeColumnMode = AllCellsExceptHeader.

It all works fine, except that some columns are just too wide. I would like to be able to set a "MaxWidth" property, such that the column will resize according to the cell contents, up to a maximum of MaxWidth. Columns have a MinWidth property, but no MaxWidth. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Just use the DataGridView.ColumnWidthChanged event.  When e.Column.Width is too large then simply set it back.

Comment: @HansPassant I would call that an answer... :^)

Comment: Then you ought to write it and mark it as the answer.

Comment: Thank you. After trying it, It seems that column.AutoSizeMode has to be set to None to be able to change a column's width. I was hoping that whenever the table adds/remove rows that it would again try to size according to AllCellsExceptHeader (and get again get overriden if too large). Simply setting column.AutoSizeMode to none, setting the size, and immediately setting column.AutoSizeMode back to AllCellsExceptHeader doesn't work (stack overflow!) Is there a better way to achieve this than to set column.AutoSizeMode back to AllCellsExceptHeader on RowsAdded/RowsRemoved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, handling the DataGridView.ColumnWidthChanged event,  setting the column.AutoSizeMode = None and the width works.

```
    private void Grid_ColumnWidthChanged(object? sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.Width > 1000)
        {
            e.Column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;
            e.Column.Width = 1000;
        }
    }
```